# If $L=\{B : BA = 0 \}$ and $R=\{C : AC = 0 \}$, what is the dimension of $L$, and $R$? $L,R,\{A\} \subset \mathbb R_{n \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$ be a square matrix of size $n$ with rank $k \in [0,n]$. Define
$$
L = \{B \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n} : BA = 0 \}, \\
R = \{C \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n} : AC = 0 \}.
$$
What is the dimension of $L$ and $R$?

I know $L$ and $R$ are linear subspaces.
By the dimension theorem
$$
\text{nullity}(A)=n-k,
$$
so, I would be tempt to say
$$
\dim(R)=\text{nullity}(A)=n-k.
$$
but I'm not sure, because $A$ acts on $\mathbb R^n$,
while the element of $R$ acts on $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$.
For $L$, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the if $C\in R$, then the *columns* of $C$ are in $\ker A$. Let $v_1,...,v_{n-k}$ be a basis for $\ker A$. Then the $(n-k)n$ matrices with zeroes in all clumns and one of the $v_1,...,v_{n-k}$ in one of the columns form a basis for $R$. Hence $\dim R=n(n-k)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
 
$C\in R\iff $ each column of $C$ is an element of $\ker (A)$.
For $L$ is the same using the matrix $A^t$.